# Is it possible to make await + setTimeout + for loop work together?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, settimeout

I use async and for loop to test for fetch issues that might be caused by network or other issues. but testing too often It generates a request error similar to endless pings.
After returning, I want to wait 3000 milliseconds before restarting the test. This is my code:

```
 const fetchtest = async (url, opts, tries=FETCHTEST_LOOP) => {
  const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
  const errs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < tries; i++) {

    try {
      return await fetch(url, opts).then(sleep(3000)) ; // << When returned, wait 3000 ms to restart the test.
    }
    catch (err) {
      errs.push(err);
    }

}

  throw errs;
};
```

this is my log:

```
2 369 update at actiVity
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [4 of 10]
trying GET [3 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [3 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [4 of 10]
trying GET [3 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [3 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [4 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
trying GET [1 of 10]
2 370 update at actiVity
trying GET [1 of 10]
trying GET [2 of 10]
2 370 update at actiVity
2 370 update at actiVity
```

I am new to this.

**I got an answer for this. i change to @vercel/fetch API it makes me not need to use setTimeout.**

Comment: `.then` expects a function as the argument, not the result of calling a function - also mixing `await` and `promise.then` is rarely a good pattern ... why not just `await sleep(3000)` - and finally the `return` means you won't be looping more than once

Comment: no idea what you want - I'm just telling you why your code is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are trying but maybe I can give some idea.

```
 const fetchtest = async (url, opts, tries=FETCHTEST_LOOP) => {
  const errs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < tries;) {

    try {
     const response = await fetch(url, opts);
     const data = response.json()
     if (data){
    setTimeout(()=>{i++},3000)
      } 
    }
    catch (err) {
      errs.push(err);
      setTimeout(()=>{i++},3000)
    }

}

  throw errs;
};
```

it is not super elegant but at least it waits 3 seconds before restarting the loop.

Again it is not clear what you exactly want(I mean purpose of your whole task/test) and possibly there is better way to achieve.